# how to get sso token from login web service

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, single-sign-on, json-rpc

I have a problem i need to get SSO token from a login web service but i cant seem to get it. when i do a ajax post it returns a html code of the login web page. I have tried to search stackoverflow and google for hints but i get nothing. here is the java function file with web services that can be called using a url i can not post here for security reasons.
could some one give me a hint ore better yet a example hot to do this?

```
    package lv.rtu.itd.mobile.api.v1.service;



    public interface SecurityService {

    /**
     * Try to login and aquire SSO token.
     * 
     * @param username - attribute identifying person. This might me UID, email, short UID, or other supported
     *            attribues.
     * @param password - password of the user.
     * @return SSO token identifying user's session or <code>null</code> in case of invalid credentials.
     */
    String login(String username, String password);

    /**
     * Checks if there's a SSO session that can be identified by provided token.
     * 
     * @param token - token of SSO session returned by {@link #login(String, String)};
     * @return <code>true</code> if SSO session is valid, <code>false</code> otherwise.
     */
    boolean isTokenValid(String token);

    /**
     * Tries to log out the user's SSO session with given token.
     * 
     * @param token - token identifying user's SSO session.
     */
    void logout(String token);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question contains too few details. For start, sample AJAX code could be given.

Assuming [JSON-RPC](http://www.jsonrpc.org/specification) is the protocol of choice, following should work:

```
POST https://your.domain.com/api/SecurityServiceURL
Content-Type: application/json
{"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "login", "params": {"username":"yourusername","password":"yourpassword"}, "id": 1}
```

In JQuery AJAX, should look like (not tested):

```
$.ajax({
  url: 'https://your.domain.com/api/SecurityServiceURL', 
      data: JSON.stringify ({"jsonrpc": "2.0", "method": "login", "params": {"username":"yourusername","password":"yourpassword"}, "id": 1}),  
      type:"POST",
      contentType:"application/json",
      success: function (data) { 
             alert("ok");
      },
      error: function (err) {
             alert("err");
      }
   });
```